# XML Http Requests errors

Tags: javascript, responsetext

I'm trying to create a lookup that gets some xml, i have a php file that does the lookup and produces a block of xml. im using the code below to but i keep getting

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
at XMLHttpRequest.send (:1:774) and can't seem to get it working!

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

function Lookup(){

var xhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
   // code for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


xhttp.open("post", "https://lookup.php", false);
xhttp.send();


var newData = xhttp.responseText;
var objhere = JSON.parse(NewData);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works as it is, I can't reproduce the error. Maybe the error is on your server? Take a look at the Network tab in the DevTools, you can see what was send/responded. Also, the current URL in the example is not correct, it lacks the domain part.

Comment: should this "https : / / lookup.php" be "/lookup.php" perhaps?

Comment: Chrome seems to show a similar error with a malformed URL like yours. You need the domain part too. Like eamanola said `/lookup.php` might work. `/` is parsed to document root on your server, the correct address depends on your file structure.

Comment: if if put in the full url eg https://website/folder/lookup.php and look in the network tab i get a cors error "CORS error xhr"

Comment: You can do AJAX requests to your own server only, or to the resources which particulary allow CORS. On your own server you can use the relative path, `/folder/lookup.php`, it tackles the most of CORS issues with a local server too.